# Not able to click checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBvMX.png)I am trying to click a checkbox but not able to do so.
isWalkinCheckBox_xpath = //input[@type='checkbox'] (Using this I am able to point to the checkbox)

```
if ( !driver.findElement(By.xpath(isWalkinCheckBox_xpath)).isSelected() )
{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(isWalkinCheckBox_xpath)).click();
}
```

Comment: please provide DOm or url

Comment: Added the image..

Comment: This could potentially be a useful question but it needs some work. At the moment, 'enter image description here' is unacceptable, and the apparent piece of code 'isWalkinCheckBox_xpath = //input[@type='checkbox']' is not explained properly or placed in context showing its connection with the following code box.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: This is angular check box that's why. I'm pretty sure if you remove if condition and run  driver.findElement(By.xpath(isWalkinCheckBox_xpath)).click(); will click checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got the issue solved. I added Thread.sleep(5000); before checking if the check box is selected or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of **angular check box**. So you have to try something like below.

```
boolean isSelected = driver.findElemet(By.cssSelector("mat-checkbox input.mat-checkbox-input")).isSelected();
Assert(isSelected )).toBe(true);
```